# Hibernate: loading a class by its field without a table

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

I have an `Ink` class with a fixed set of constants. They never change and I don't want to store this class as a table.

```
public final class Ink {
    public static final Ink Y = new Ink(91001, 'y', 90.70,  -5.23,  94.37), "Yellow");
    public static final Ink M = new Ink(92001, 'm', 48.19,  72.01,  -1.78), "Magenta");
    public static final Ink C = new Ink(93001, 'c', 56.46, -41.00, -43.50), "Cyan");
    public static final Ink K = new Ink(94001, 'k', 18.64,   1.80,   5.21), "Black");      

    public int code;

    public static Ink forCode(int code) {
        //...
    }

    //...
}
```

Other classes can have `Ink ink` or `Collection<Ink> inks` fields, but every `ink` instance must be mapped as a simple integer column with its `code` value only. `Code` is not a foreign key or something – it is a simple integer value from which I can always obtain `Ink` instance.

```
@Entity
public class Order {
     //...
     @OneToMany    
     public Set<Ink> inks;
     //...
}
```

I can use converter to restore `Ink` class by its `code` and back

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class InkConverter implements AttributeConverter<Ink, Integer> {

     @Overrcodee
     public Integer convertToDatabaseColumn(Ink ink) {
         return ink.code;
     }

     @Overrcodee
     public Ink convertToEntityAttribute(Integer code) {
         return Ink.forCode(code);
     }
}
```

but the question is:

**how to prevent Hibernate from mapping the class as a table and still have a class field loaded from its `code` column?**

Comment: Why would Hibernate map __Ink__ as a table when it doesn't have an @Entity annotation? No compliant JPA implementation would do that.

Answer (score 1):

As you store the ink in your Java code. So you should implement the load action all by your self. First, you can prevent Hibernate from mapping the class as a table by annotation @Transient. And then you can handle the load action after order loaded:

```
public interface Inked {
    getCode();
    setInk(Ink ink);
}

public abstract class AbstractEntity {

    @PostLoad
    public void loadInk() {
        if(this instanceof Inked){
            Inked inked = (Inked) this;
            inked.setInk(Ink.forCode(getCode()));
        }
    }
}

@Entity
public class Order extends AbstractEntity implement Inked {
    //...
    public Integer code;

    @Transient
    public Ink ink;
    //...

}
```

Comment: Good, but in this case I need to attach`loadInk()` and `code` to every entity with `Ink` field.

Comment: If you have many entity to have the ink. May be you do it use the interface. Code updated.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you can create an Enum to represent Ink instances. If you can change the column to store a char reference (Y,M,C,K) rather than code this would the easiest solution. If not then you can use a converter as you have suggested to convert from the code to the Enum instance.

```
public Enum Ink {
    Y = new Ink(91001, 'y', 90.70,  -5.23,  94.37), "Yellow");
    M = new Ink(92001, 'm', 48.19,  72.01,  -1.78), "Magenta");
    C = new Ink(93001, 'c', 56.46, -41.00, -43.50), "Cyan");
    K = new Ink(94001, 'k', 18.64,   1.80,   5.21), "Black"); 

    .....     

    private static Ink (...) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Mappings would be like the below if you save Y,M,C,K. If you must save the code then add the necessary converters (http://www.nurkiewicz.com/2013/06/mapping-enums-done-right-with-convert.html)

```
@Entity
public class Order {

     @ElementCollection   
     @CollectionTable(...)
     @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
     public Set<Ink> inks;

     @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
     private Ink ink;
}
```